# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code for for Registration Site

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code runs fine but when I login user to new registration of user I get the following error.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from Table where Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already Exists");
            }


            conn.Close();
```

Sql Exception occurs at line int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

Any idea what this might be.

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: Put the result of com.ExecuteScalar() in a temporary variable, insert a breakpoint and debug.

Comment: If this code runs fine, which code causes error?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: When I input data into the registration page fails to load (time out). VB points at int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());  and get this message. An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: what is the ACTUAL exception.... look at the inner exception but you can still use a try catch block and see what the exception is and write it out to a log file or database or on the screen or whatever

Answer (score 2):

**Table** is a reserved keyword in T-SQL. If you have a table named **Table**, you must escape it in your SQL statements:

```
select count(*) from [Table]
```

(Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

And please, use parameterized queries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection